# Is there any similar function as of FORMAT in SQL Server 2008 or 2010

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

AS [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) :

> `FORMAT` Returns a value formatted with the specified format and
>   optional culture in SQL Server 2012. Use the `FORMAT` function for
>   locale-aware formatting of date/time and number values as strings.

Is this or any similar function available in 2008 or R2 or 2010 for formatting purpose?

**Update:
I don't know too. But I heard Microsoft released some SQL Version code-named 'Denali' in year 2010 as Sql 2010 or 2011**

Comment: There's no such thing as SQL Server 2010, perhaps you are talking about Visual Studio 2010. I'm not sure what version of SQL Server it is usually bundled with but probably 2008 R2 (at least 2008, I guess).

Comment: First of all: **there is no SQL Server 2010** ... there are versions 2008, 2008 R2, 2012. Second: **no** there is no such function in 2008 and 2008 R2 - it's a new 2012 feature. **New** as is : it didnt' exist before.

Comment: You could write a CLR function using the `.NET` framework formatting functions on previous versions though.

Comment: Denali was the pre-release name for SQL Server 2012. It is not a separate product.

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit FORMAT function, but if you are converting a datatype to a string (such as date etc) the CONVERT function supports different formats that can be applied by specifying the correct code.

The codes are detailed here:

[CAST and CONVERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

e.g. if you wanted to format a datetime as a string with the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS", you could use the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120)
```

Where the code 120 is the style.

It works for more than just dates too, I've used it with varbinary and XML data too.